# Limit of a sequence with logs

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms

Started this question but stuck a bit of the way through it:

> $$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \Bigl(\frac{cos (\theta) +\frac{1}{n}}{cos(\theta)}\Bigr)^n \\= \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} log\Bigl(\frac{cos (\theta) +\frac{1}{n}}{cos(\theta)}\Bigr)^n \\= \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} n \log\Bigl(\frac{cos (\theta) +\frac{1}{n}}{cos(\theta)}\Bigr) \\= \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} n \log\Bigl(\sec{(\theta)(\cos(\theta)+\frac{1}{n})}\Bigr)$$

Help would be fantastic.

Comment: I guess without taking the log, it would be easier: re-write the limit as $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} (1+\dfrac{1/cos(\theta)}{n})^n$. Then, try to use the known limit : $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} (1+\dfrac{1}{n})^n=e$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{aligned}\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} n \log\Bigl(\sec{(\theta)(\cos(\theta)+\frac{1}{n})}\Bigr) &=
\lim_{n\to\infty} n\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n\cos\theta}\right) \\
&=\lim\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n\cos\theta}\right)^n \\
&=\log \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n\cos\theta}\right)^n \\
&=\log e^{\sec\theta} \\
&= \sec\theta\\
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for but I am being a bit stupid towards the end. Where is the exponential coming from between the 3rd last and 2nd last step? Thanks

Comment: This is because $e=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$, and $e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$

Answer (score 1):

write your term in the form
$$\left( \left(1+\frac{1}{n\cos(\theta)}\right)^{n\cos(\theta)}\right)^{1/\cos(\theta)}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$L = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \Bigl(\frac{\cos (\theta) +\frac{1}{n}}{\cos(\theta)}\Bigr)^n\\
=\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \Bigl(1 +\frac{1}{n\cos\theta}\Bigr)^n\\
=e^{1/\cos\theta}$$

You have to know the special limit that produces $e^x.$